# External access from Vendors

Tags: workflow, permissions, external-list, approval-process

How can I grant access to external users?

The idea is the external user can:

1. Access some of my SharePoint list so I can collect information from them (We temporary hire some vendors), this list will collect names from the people that will be working with us. The idea is that this list have approval flow. In case some info is missing we will NOT conclude the hiring process.
2. Save files only in a specific folder.

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: 2016 Sharepoint version.

Comment: Any news guys? I have no idea how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options available.  You can implement a FBA provider for your external users, or you can look into something like Google / FaceBook / LinkedIn / etc.... authentication.  With FBA you would need to pre-provision the accounts, while with another provider you just need to pre-permission the users.  Point 1 and 2 can both be handled by SharePoint permissions, you just need to pick an external user solution.  If you want to go with FBA, I would look into FBASuite.  And if you want to go with a social provider, I would look into Auth0.